# What does the flags parameter of ArrayIterator and ArrayObject do?

Tags: php, spl, arrayobject, arrayiterator

The constructors of PHP's `ArrayIterator` and `ArrayObject` have a `flags` parameter that is documented in [`ArrayObject::setFlags()`](http://php.net/arrayobject.setflags) as follows:

> **`ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST`**
>
> Properties of the object have their normal functionality when accessed as list (var_dump, foreach, etc.).
>
> **`ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS`**
>
> Entries can be accessed as properties (read and write).

The documentation of ArrayIterator::setFlags() is similar ([the difference being difference erroneous](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-notes/122ve776vq/note-107695-added-to-arrayiterator-setflags)).

Now, I understand the second flag quite well, it allows property access with `->` as well as array access with `[]`:

```php
$a = new ArrayIterator(array('foo'=>1), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
var_dump($a['foo']);
var_dump($a->foo);
```

```
int(1)
int(1)
```

But I cannot wrap my head around `ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST`. As far as I tested it, `var_dump` and `foreach` behave exactly the same with or without this flag. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#105481) in the PHP manual the flag causes the properties, instead of the array values to be visible in `var_dump`.

Credits for this go to [the commenter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#105481) in the PHP manual:

```
<?php                                                    

$a = new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);
    $a['arr'] = 'array data';                            
    $a->prop = 'prop data';                              
$b = new ArrayObject();                                  
    $b['arr'] = 'array data';                            
    $b->prop = 'prop data';                              

// ArrayObject Object                                    
// (                                                     
//      [prop] => prop data                              
// )                                                     
print_r($a);                                             

// ArrayObject Object                                    
// (                                                     
//      [arr] => array data                              
// )                                                     
print_r($b);                                             

?>
```

This behaviour probably changed within never versions of PHP, as my version (5.4.6) of PHP always shows both: Properties and array values:

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [prop] => prop data
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [arr] => array data
        )

)
ArrayObject Object
(
    [prop] => prop data
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [arr] => array data
        )

)
```

Comment: So, the flag would be meaningless by now? Thanks for pointing out the comment section of ArrayObject, I only looked at the comments of the particular methods.

Comment: @fab You should check the quoted code by yourself to find out whether this applies to you as well.

Comment: I tried it on PHP 5.4 and 5.3, got the same behaviour like you. Also, `foreach` always ignores the properties.

Comment: php 5.5.12 here. `print_r` gives the same behaviour as mentioned in the answer, but using `var_dump` shows similar behaviour to the comment from php manual.

Comment: @fschmengler `foreach` probably ignores it because it's `private` and inaccessible.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the private property.